# Easy/simple input method package that works with minimal window manager?

Tags: xorg, input, input-method

I am trying out minimalist window managers such as, but not limited to, Xmonad, ScrotWM, ratpoison, etc.
Since I occasionally need to enter Traditional Chinese characters, how do I install an input manager that lets me switch between input methods easily, such as through a hotkey combo? Any instructions would be appreciated.

Comment: I doubt this is really window manager specific; the window manager mostly just manages windows. If you're using the WM to catch the hotkey and run the program that part is WM-specific, but you're really just looking for a program that lets you switch input methods so you can tell your WM to run it when you press a certain hotkey

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Michael suggests, the window manager is not responsible for managing the input method. First you will need to choose an [input method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_input_methods_for_UNIX_platforms), of which `IBus`, `SCIM` and `uim` appear to be the most popular.

Next, you need to make sure it is started when `X` is launched. You've mentioned you are using a lightweight WM, therefore you'll likely want to add it to an X init file, such as
`~/.xinitrc`:

```
export GTK_IM_MODULE=scim
export XMODIFIERS=@im=SCIM
export QT_IM_MODULE=scim
scim -d
```

Depending on the input method you choose, the method to switch languages will differ. Typically, you'll need to `export LANG`, such as

```
export LANG=ja_JA.UTF-8
```

... but sometimes right clicking on an input field and choosing "Input Methods" may suffice.

Answer (score 5):

I use Ratpoison WM. To type Chinese, I simply added IBUS to the `~/.ratpoisonrc` file, which then starts IBUS when you start Ratpoison. The line looks like this:

```
exec ibus-daemon --xim
```

If you aren't using Ratpoison, arrange to launch `ibus-daemon --xim` when your X session start by whatever means your window manager or session manager provides.

Then, to start typing in Chinese, type both Control+SpaceBar as normal.

Comment: Isn't Control+SpaceBar reserved by ratpoison to visit the next window by default? i'm asking, because I use ratpoison as well, and I can't seem to find how to activate ibus (inputing japanese). Am I supposed to switch to a japanese keyboard layout first?